# Excel 2016 won't break down data for a chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I just started MS Office 2016 Excel on my Mac, but I can't get it to create pie charts for me. Even if I choose a column of data, it seems Excel thinks it is a single piece of data. Switching between columns and rows doesn't solve this for me. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting/hoping to get? 
A pie chart that’s ¾ (6/8) one color and ¼ (2/8) another? 
You can’t give it text like that; you have to give it numbers (6 and 2). 
Use `COUNTIF` or an equivalent function on your text column to count the values.

Comment: oooh... expecting my approach to work was really a no-brainer for me. Must have been a long time since I last created a chart. I can only hope in a few years Excel will get even smarter than it is now and do all this extra work for me too.

Thank you so much for your time!